# How to create async gRPC with more than one method?

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm trying to implement async RPC for multiple methods and going by their async greeter [server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.33.2/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc)/[client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.33.2/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc) example, it's not entirely clear how the server handles different methods as the example only implements a single method for the server, `SayHello` and there's no corresponding method named `SayHello` on the server like there is for the [synchronous version](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.33.2/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc).

Instead, the logic for handling `SayHello` seems to be handled in the `Proceed` function. If I wanted to create another method, do I just handle it all in Proceed? And if so, how would I do that?

```
void Proceed() {
      if (status_ == CREATE) {
        // Make this instance progress to the PROCESS state.
        status_ = PROCESS;

        // As part of the initial CREATE state, we *request* that the system
        // start processing SayHello requests. In this request, "this" acts are
        // the tag uniquely identifying the request (so that different CallData
        // instances can serve different requests concurrently), in this case
        // the memory address of this CallData instance.
        service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                                  this);
      } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
        // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients while we process
        // the one for this CallData. The instance will deallocate itself as
        // part of its FINISH state.
        new CallData(service_, cq_);

        // The actual processing.
        std::string prefix("Hello ");
        reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());

        // And we are done! Let the gRPC runtime know we've finished, using the
        // memory address of this instance as the uniquely identifying tag for
        // the event.
        status_ = FINISH;
        responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
      } else {
        GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
        // Once in the FINISH state, deallocate ourselves (CallData).
        delete this;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [doc](https://grpc.github.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp.html) would be helpful to understand about how the async server is constructed.

For your question, you can add more CallData for another rpc method. e.g. Writing a CallData2 for an imaginary method Hello2. Both CallData and CallData2 might have to inherit CallDataBase which has virtual Proceed function so that both can be handled by `static_cast<CallDataBase*>(tag)->Proceed();`